# SVG Frame Animation

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I was curious if anybody could point me in the right direction to be able to do SVG animation where it essentially cycles the visibility of grouped elements so that essentially you have a frame by frame animation. The animation code has to be embedded inside the svg and has to be compatible with IE, Firefox and Chrome. So far after countless hours of trying different things I've gotten it to work in Chrome only.

Comment: IE doesn't do SMIL or CSS animation so you'll need to use a javascript animation library or code it yourself.

Comment: Ok, well I've been informed that I can forget the IE compatibility and just make it compatible with Firefox and Chrome. Is it possible to do this while maintaining compatibility across those two browsers?

Comment: In that case use SMIL or CSS animation.

Comment: Can you embed SMIL or CSS animations directly in an SVG file's code? I tried doing this but it didn't work...

Comment: Sure you can, post the code in your question and I'll correct it if it's short enough.

Comment: Well this is the code I have right now, I don't like the fading I'd rather it just cycle frames on or off. http://codepen.io/chrisbtbi/pen/wzbJNo

Comment: By the way, there is a lot of code but the animation code is very short and at the end of each group of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SMIL specification says that numbers cannot start with a . so you need

```
dur="0.1s"
```

Change that and it seems to work in Firefox, i.e. the blades look like they are moving which is presumably what you're trying to do. Chrome is less strict and allows things that are technically invalid.

You could probably get this to work in IE by using a SMIL emulation library such as [fakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much Robert!